# Displaying errors in slack modal view

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a modal which will enable the users to input a date for further use. This date cannot be a date from the past or present (only future dates). Slack indicates that it is possible to validate input data and display errors in the modal views [here](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors) but I don't really understand this method (I'm a self-learner and a greenhorn).

here's my `view`object in the `view.open`:

```html
{
          type: "modal",
          callback_id: "tests",
          title: {
            type: "plain_text",
            text: "Tests",
            emoji: true
          },
          submit: {
            type: "plain_text",
            text: "Send",
            emoji: true
          },
          close: {
            type: "plain_text",
            text: "Cancel",
            emoji: true
          },
          blocks: [
            {
              type: "input",
              block_id: "datepicker",
              optional: false,
              element: {
                action_id: "calendar",
                type: "datepicker",
                initial_date: "2020-09-05",
                placeholder: {
                  type: "plain_text",
                  text: "Select a date",
                  emoji: true
                }
              },
              label: {
                type: "plain_text",
                text: "Label",
                emoji: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

I need help with displaying the error in the view ( I can already describe that error) after receiving `view_submission`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

First, I highly recommend that, in your code, you change the `block_id` from "datepicker" to something more descriptive. Slack's example uses "ticket-due-date", so I'll use that.

When a date is entered, Slack will send an HTTP POST request to the endpoint you specified in the Interactivity Request URL. That payload will look something like this (acquired from [Block Kit Builder](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder)):

```
{
    "type": "block_actions",
    "user": {
        "id": "U0CA5",
        "username": "Amy McGee",
        "name": "Amy McGee",
        "team_id": "T3MDE"
    },
    "api_app_id": "A0CA5",
    "token": "Shh_its_a_seekrit",
    "container": {
        "type": "message",
        "text": "The contents of the original message where the action originated"
    },
    "trigger_id": "12466734323.1395872398",
    "team": {
        "id": "T0CAG",
        "domain": "acme-creamery"
    },
    "response_url": "https://www.postresponsestome.com/T123567/1509734234",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "datepicker",
            "block_id": "ticket-due-date",
            "action_id": "vxw",
            "selected_date": "1990-04-26",
            "initial_date": "1990-04-28",
            "action_ts": "1599429672.233568"
        }
    ]
}
```

When you receive that request, you need to validate `actions[0].selected_date`. If invalid, then send the payload below as a POST request to `response_url`.

```
{
  "response_action": "errors",
  "errors": {
    "ticket-due-date": "You may not select a due date in the past"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a `response_url`. Only a `trigger_id`. Is there anything to add?

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to the same request that is calling your endpoint.

Here's how the interaction endpoint would look like:

```html
app.post("/your_endpoint", (req, res) => {
  const validationErrors = {
    datepicker: "Please enter a valid date"
  };

  // Respond to the request with an error payload
  res.send({
    response_action: "errors",
    errors: validationErrors,
  });
});
```